# How do I deserialize the JSON response into my list?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, json-deserialization

I want to parse the following JSON response:

```
{
  "message": "string",
  "errorCode": "string",
  "totalSize": 0,
  "offset": 0,
  "done": true,
  "nextRecordsUrl": "string",
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "external_ID_vod__c": "string",
      "vExternal_Id_vod__c": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note that there are multiple 'records'

The relevant class I am using to deserialize the JSON response is:

```
public class RecordProduct
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string external_ID_vod__c { get; set; }
            public string vExternal_Id_vod__c { get; set; }
        }

public class Products
        {
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string errorCode { get; set; }
            public int totalSize { get; set; }
            public int offset { get; set; }
            public bool done { get; set; }
            public string nextRecordsUrl { get; set; }
            public List<RecordProduct> records { get; set; }

        }
```

The code that is calling the API:

```
public void getAllProductInfo()
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("blahblahblah/");

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/api/Products", Method.GET);

            string securityToken = getBearerToken();
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + securityToken);

            IRestResponse<JsonResponseSetup.Datum.Products> response = client.Execute<JsonResponseSetup.Datum.Products>(request);

            var res = response.Data.records;
            res.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

         }
```

When I execute the last line: `res.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` I do not get the records to print.

**Edit**: I figured it out. I was just accessing the members of records incorrectly.
The following worked in place of the last two line of my code.

```
foreach(var item in response.Data.records)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"name: {item.name}, id: {item.id}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) is an easy to use framework that will help you convert to and from .NET and JSON objects, as you'll see in [this example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) from the documentation.

In short, you just pass your JSON to the `DeserializeObject` method and specify which class the corresponding JSON should be parsed to.

Comment: I think in the new RestSharp, they have removed the dependency on that framework. Also the example you linked, is very basic, I'm more interested in parsing into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Products facebookFriends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Products>(result);
```